# How to automatize overriding methods?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, composite

I am wondering if there is any tricky way to override all class methods in the same manner. For instance, how to wisely implement composite pattern in large classes? When i get something like this for instance:

```
        class Foo{
            virtual void work() = 0;
...
        };

        class FooLeaf : public Foo{
            virtual void work() override{}
...
        };

        class FooComposite : public Foo{
            std::vector<Foo *> foos;
            virtual void work() override{
                for (auto foo : foos){
                    foo->work();
                }
            }
...
        };
```

It is not a problem to reimplement one method. But when the number of methods grows the code get tremendously WET. I mean, I don't feel good copy-pasting the foreach loop for, let's say, 10 methods.

Comment: Why would you copy that loop N times?  if it does the same thing in each class just implement it in the base class...

Comment: @EdS. You didn't undrestand what i meant. I am asking what should I do when i have multiple different methods in Foo and want to implement them differently in FooComposite. Generally they look very much alike inside FooComposite, when they are overriden - for loop and inside method from foos stored in vector.

Comment: God bless 'em - macros are *terrific* for this stuff... ;-).

Comment: Ok... I was just going off of what you said... *"I mean, I don't feel good copy-pasting the foreach loop for, let's say, 10 methods."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is to get rid of the loop, but you don't mind repeating the method name, you could encapsulate the iteration (and potentially any error handling) in a `Composite` template, and then you can use a lambda to forward the call through to each element of the composite.

```
template <typename ElementType>
class Composite : public ElementType {
 private:
    std::vector<ElementType*> container;

 protected:
    template < typename Fn>
    auto apply (Fn && fn) {
        for (auto& e : container) {
            fn(*e);
        }
    }
};

class Foo{
 public:
    virtual void work() = 0;
};

class FooLeaf : public Foo{
    virtual void work() override { }
};

class FooComposite : public Composite<Foo> {
    virtual void work() override {
        return apply([](Foo& f){f.work();});
    }
};
```

Even better, you can encapsulate the addition of elements to the composite via the Composite class template, which is arguably where it belongs.  The implementation of `apply` relies on some C++14 type deduction features to make it a bit easier to write and to look at.

Comment: This is mostly what i wanted but there is still problem when i want to override about 10 methods in composite, Or even worse - when i try to create generic composite and don't really know the number of base class methods. I mean - there are still very similar parts of code that are amost copy-pasted.

Comment: I think that's when you have to resort to macros, or some other code-generating tool like your IDE.  The problem is that the language cannot reasonably guess what virtual methods from its bases should be implemented.  That knowledge is the domain of the programmer, not the language.

Comment: I should also say, this usage of `apply` could be further simplified by the use of generic lambdas that should be available in an upcoming standard, and in many compilers sooner than that.

Answer (score 1):

If all methods have the same signature, you can use method pointers:

```
class Foo{
  public:
    virtual void work() = 0;
    virtual void rest() = 0;
};

class FooComposite : public Foo {
  std::vector<Foo *> foos;

  void do_all(void (Foo::*method)()) {
    for (auto foo : foos) {
      (foo->*method)();
    }
  }

  void work() override {
    do_all(&Foo::work);
  }
  void rest() override {
    do_all(&Foo::rest);
  }
};
```

Comment: Nice, but - nitpicking, sorry - it would be better to specify `override` instead of `virtual` in `FooComposite`.  Not that it's needed or useful for this exact Q, but this can be generalised into a visitor pattern.